# Is it possible to change attribute of individual UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to make changes to a particular UITableViewCell? For example, change the text in one cell of a table view with a button click?

Comment: Using UITableView.reloadRows([IndexPath], animation: .automatic)

Comment: @HHumorous thanks, that helped me find what I need which is: (myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell).customSubview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you should not do that.

As you said in your comment, you *can* ask the table view for a cell and then make changes to that cell, but don't do that.

You should do what HHumorous said, and change your data model, then tell the table view to reload the affected cell.

If you simply change the appearance of the cell, then when the user scrolls that cell off-screen and then back on-screen the changes will be lost.